# Object appears at least twice in list?

Tags: racket

Let's say we have a: `(list 1 2 3 5 2 6 7 4)`

I want to know if `2` appears at least twice.

`member?` checks if it appears at all. I suppose I could check `member?` then run `remove` then check `member?` again. Is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`count`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29), which receives a `lambda` for checking any condition you want and a list to be checked. It returns the number of elements in the list that meet the condition:

```
(count (lambda (n) (= n 2)) (list 1 2 3 5 2 6 7 4))
=> 2
```

Then it's a simple matter to verify if the count fulfills the requirement that the number appears at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

One can use member function with recursion to check if first element is the desired number and is also part of rest of the list- then loop again with rest of the list:

```
(define (is_duplicated n L)
  (let loop ((L L))
    (cond
      [(empty? L) #f]
      [(and (= n (first L))
            (member n (rest L))) #t]
      [else (loop (rest L))]
      )))

(is_duplicated 2 (list 1 2 3 5 2 6 7 4))
```

Note that it is "member" and not "member?" which is part of Racket base functions (https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=member%3F).